# Полностью автоматическая генерация документации для API

Tags: php, laravel

Использую в проекте https://github.com/mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator
для создания документации.

Возникло несколько проблем.

- Не отображает в параметрах реквеста правил валидации для элемента
  массива, т.е.

  `'array.*.item' => 'required|bool'`
- Не отображает кастомных правил для полей, хотя в самих правилах метод
  `__toString` описан.

По первой проблеме -  в этом [файле](https://github.com/mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator/blob/master/src/Mpociot/ApiDoc/Generators/AbstractGenerator.php) метод `getParameters` получает праметры из валидатора но все кроме правил для элементов массива.

Как можно заставить валидатор возвращать все правила которые описаны для роута ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И так по проблеме отображения элементов массива из реквеста:
Убрал валидатор, правила валидации мы получаем напрямую с роута, добавил метод для разбития правил по аналогии с валидатором:

```
$validatorRules = $this->getRules($this->getRouteRules($routeAction['uses'], $bindings));
```

Для решения второй проблемы - добавил несколько кастомных типов (custom_string,custom_integer, custom_boolean,custom_date), их можно использовать описав кастомное правило в методе `__toString`, к примеру

```
custom_string:Custom rule description
```

Сделал форк с фиксом данных проблем.

https://github.com/mykolaivashchuk/laravel-apidoc-generator